# CSS/HTML: mouse down on cancel

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent, mousedown

I have a link being themed using CSS. I have up, over and down CSS properties applied which all work.

Problem is, when you hold down the mouse over a button, drag away then cancel by letting go, the down state is still being applied until you click again on some white-space.

You can see what I mean by doing the above on buttons 1, 2 and 4 here: http://jsfiddle.net/2vjbz/

How do you 'refresh' by not having to click again?

Comment: FYI, this is not happening in Chrome but is for me in Firefox 8.0.1.

Comment: Looks like a Firefox and IE bug to me.  FF 9.0.1 and IE 9 are doing the same thing.

Comment: It seems #pager a:active pseudo-class causing to this. It may be a bug.

Comment: Its about the mouse down event, Focus is set on a html element after a successful onmouse down. And I think this behavior is correct.

Comment: Maybe you can use javascript to fix this if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your CSS, I think this behavior is correct, but the problem is that mouse up event is not getting triggered and link element remains in active state. You can fix it using jQuery by invoking mouse up event for link element.

One method is to invoke it when mouse moves in pager div

```
$('#pager').bind("mousemove", function(event) {
    $('#pager a').mouseup();
});
```

You might need to add conditions to make it perfect

EDIT:

You can experiment with it. This is one more method

http://jsfiddle.net/diode/2vjbz/18/

Here it cancels the drag event. Both of these worked for me.

Comment: Thanks - the code fires, but the same issue is their. Do you have any other tips on how I could make it work?

Comment: please check the jsfiddle demo given in the updated answer. In that I am cancelling the drag. Actually both of the methods worked for me using the html in your jsfiddle .